How to configure UserSecret in a C# WPF app with IHostBuilder
I managed to configure UserSecret in a console app where I basically replace App by Program, but it seems that the following (simplified) code does not seem to work with a WPF app.
public static IHostBuilder AddServices(this IHostBuilder host)
{
    host.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddUserSecrets<App>() // I don't know if it is 'App' to use as the generic.
            .Build();

        var config = builder.GetSection(nameof(UserSecretModel));

        services.Configure<UserSecretModel>(config);
    });
    
    return host;
}

Can someone share his insights?

It is helpful to read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecretsconfigurationextensions.addusersecrets?view=net-8.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-usersecretsconfigurationextensions-addusersecrets-1(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfigurationbuilder)

Do you want to use that in production? What problem do you want to solve with it?

The app will only be used by myself, so it doesn't really matter whether it is in production or development. I can get the User Secret values if I inspect the builder variable, but it seems it is not added to the services. Do App and UserSecretModel be in the same namescope?

I believe I got confused with the GetSection() which I eventually removed and everything seems to work fine.
public static IHostBuilder AddServices(this IHostBuilder host)
{
    host.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddUserSecrets<App>
            .Build();

        services.Configure<UserSecretModel>(configuration);
    });
    
    return host;
}

